# @Html.Beginform() not rendering properly IE7-8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I have a HTML form which is in a partial that is loaded via jquery.load(). My partial looks something like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "addComicForm"}){ 
<div class="add-comic-submit">
    <input type="submit" value="haha" name="haha" />
</div>
}
```

On IE7-8 It's not rendered properly and does not create a form attribute, however, if I manually insert the form code such as

```
<form action="/ManageComics/ComicAdder" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addComicForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"> </form>
```

It works properly.

Comment: Who cares. It's internet explorer. Not to mention version 7 and 8

Comment: @Cole don't ignore the ~ 20% market share of IE8.

Comment: @CodeCaster IE8 is more like 5%...

Comment: @PWKad I find claims from [23%](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), [10%](http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-may-2013/) [5%](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) and all numbers in between. You do not want 1 out of 5-20 people not to be able to use your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are doing it wrong. It should be like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ComicAdder", "ManageComics", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "addComicForm" }))
{ 
    <div class="add-comic-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="haha" name="haha" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. When inspecting the html, all I see is the `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm{ }` and no <form> tag above it. Same thing when I use the method I provided above.

Comment: Please check your code again, and make sure it's like the one in my answer. You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: BTW, is this form inside an if block or something?

Comment: It's inside a div.
I have a jquery.load() which loads my partial view containing my Html.BeginForm() into a hidden div on my main page.

Comment: Ok, I tried this solution and it didn't work at first, but now it is working. Maybe I typed it wrong. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

another way should like this:

```
@{
    Html.BeginForm("your actionName", "your controllerName", FormMethod.Post);
}
<div class="add-comic-submit">
   <input type="submit" value="haha" name="haha" />
</div>
@{
    Html.EndForm();
}
```